# Appearing Event is not getting called

Tags: maui

Whenever I navigate to a page via `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Page");` the cross platform event "Appearing" is getting triggered in "Page".
The "Appearing" event is also getting triggered when I pop to "Page" via `Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();`.

But when I push a page modal onto "Page" via `Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());` and then pop this "Page2" with `Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync();` in "Page2" then the "Appearing" event is not getting triggered in "Page".
Does someone know if this is intendet or if it is a Bug?
If this is not a Bug, is there a way to register when "Page" is Appearing or in focus again so I can do something then?

Steps to reproduce:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Page")
```

In "Page":

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
```

In "Page2":

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

=> Lifecycle Event Appearing is not getting triggered in "Page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it is an already registered Bug.

[Github Ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8513)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, when you push a modal,alert or a popup (with community toolkit), the main page who invoke that it's still there, so you couldn't trigger appearing method.

Solution 1: [EventTriggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers)

```
<ContentPage.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="LayoutChanged" >
        YourTriggerThatFocusHere
    </EventTrigger>
</ContentPage.Triggers>
```

Layout changed event is fired after and before you push a modal so you could use it in this way. And in your local trigger you set the focus on the control you want with **"controlname".Focus()**

Solution 2 (for MVVM) if you need to fire a command you could use eventToCommand behavior with the same layout changed event:

```
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"

<ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="LayoutChanged"
                                    Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

Comment: When I use the first methode to trigger the event in "Page" so where I push something modal and pop back the event is only getting called the first time when I navigate to "Page" with `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Page");` is this normal? Or is there another option that im missing?

Comment: im actually using the solution 2, using shell.current.navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2()); and get the command executed on modal closed. are you using last version of vs preview?

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8904), This is only a issue on Android, works fine on iOS.